# Unable to resolve module by using native-base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I take a reference from https://docs.nativebase.io/ , when i try to use the sample code it shows the error `Unable to resolve module` , it just like the photo
[image]
My environment is:

```
"expo": "^18.0.4",
"native-base": "^2.2.1",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-18.0.1.tar.gz",
```

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
// import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Button, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Button>
          <Text>
            Button
          </Text>
        </Button>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I find that i just import 'native-base' cause the error `import { Container, Button, Text } from 'native-base';`

Please tell me what step i miss it . Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you update your react-native version , unmet peer dependency issue it seems

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i found the answer that is npm version 2.2.0 , if still want to use 2.2.1 , RN must be 0.46 up.

Answer (score 9):

I think you have forgot to install the `native-base` component first, if not then use the following command inside your project

```
npm install native-base --save
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i found the answer that is npm version 2.2.0 , if still want to use 2.2.1 , RN must be 0.46 up.

Comment: You also need to run npm start again after installing. Commenting just for the beginners.